# Rails: undefined method `total_price' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I'm building a concert ticket sales application with Rails 3.0.4, working primarily with the Agile Web Development tutorial (http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) and trying to incorporate Ryan Bate's order purchase method (http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout). Everything works with the following in orders_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
  @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip 

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
  Notifier.order_received(@order).deliver
  format.html { redirect_to(calendar_url, :notice => 'Thank you for your order.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }
  Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
  session[:cart_id] = nil
else
  format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
  end
```

But when I add "&& @order.purchase" to the conditional clause, with the order.rb model as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  belongs_to :cart
  #...

  def price_in_cents
    (cart.total_price*100).round
  end

  def purchase
    response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
    cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
    response.success?
  end
  #...
end
```

I receive an "undefined method `total_price' for nil:NilClass" error. I can get around this by adding

```
@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
```

to the orders "create" method, but this messes up the "order_received" notification by somehow preventing the pertinent order information (in this case "@order.line_items") from rendering in the e-mail text.

The "cart" object is being set to nil somewhere along the way, but removing

```
Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
```

from the order "create" method does not fix the problem.

Anyone got a clue for this noob?

Comment: The problem is with the association. As posted by @muffinista you need to set it. `@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])` should do the trick. What do you mean with it messed the notification somehow? what did you expect and what you got?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the Cart object is ever actually specified in the belongs_to relation, you need to either do `@order.cart = current_cart`, or `current_cart.order = Order.new`, or something along those lines.

Comment: It turns out that "@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])" is not what's messing up the notification, but rather something in the purchase method. When I have "@order.save && @order.purchase" in the controller, the notification text (order_received.text.erb) produces a blank space at <%= render(@order.line_items) %>, whereas with just "@order.save" the line items are properly rendered.

Comment: I would check to see if line_items is being properly populated now.  It's not clear from the code you've included either way.

Comment: WEBrick seems to indicate that they are: "Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML...[36mLineItem Load (0.0ms)←[0m ←[[imSELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".order_id = 248)←[0m". Also, I'd think that the following code from the order model might be relevant:

    def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
      cart.line_items.each do |item|
 item.cart_id = nil
 line_items << item
      end
    end

Is there anything in the purchase method (shown in original post) that might prevent "@order.line_items" from rendering in the notification?

Comment: You should really explicitly check to see if they are being added and/or saved to the db.  There's nothing in your output to confirm that.

Comment: They are only saved to the db when the purchase method is removed from the if-clause AND "@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])" is commented out.